# Mysql PDO statement with OR in SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use OR in the statement below, in the statement below i select in one ID_klant, but i want to select on 2 different id's

```
try {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT *
    FROM inkoop t10
    WHERE t10.ID_klant = :ID_klant
    AND t10.factuurdatum_timestamp >= :timestamp_start
    AND t10.factuurdatum_timestamp < :timestamp_eind
    GROUP BY t10.ID_inkoop');
$stmt->bindParam(':ID_klant', $ID_klant, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':timestamp_start', $begin_jaar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':timestamp_eind', $eind_jaar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: So what issue are you having? I'd also use `between`.. `t10.factuurdatum_timestamp between :timestamp_start and :timestamp_eind`.

Comment: Sorry i changed the question

Comment: you may want to use `IN()` and use an array beforehand

Comment: I saw that, but how...

Comment: Thanks Chris, that did the job!

Comment: I feel that @chris85 should post an answer based on his comment. I only gave a suggestion/example.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, posted.

Comment: And accepted chris, thanks

Comment: You're welcome @chris85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` to check if a column has a series of values in it. Here's how you'd use it with placeholders:

```
WHERE t10.ID_klant in (:ID_klant, :second_placeholder)
```

Then just bind `:second_placeholder` and `:ID_klant`.